# Let $X$ be a random variable with values in $\mathbb{Z}$ and distribution function $F$, given by $F(x) := P(X ≤ x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions

Express the following probabilities using $F$: 
a) $P(X > 18), P(X > k), P(X ≥ 5), P(X ≥ k)$ 
b) $P(X = 5), P(X = k)$ 
c) $P(4 < X ≤ 11), P(a < X ≤ b), P(8 ≤ X < 25), P(a ≤ X < b)$ 
d) $P(X ≤ 2 \text{ } $or$ \text{ } X ≥ 5), P(X ≤ 6 \text{ } $and$ \text{ } X ≥ −3)$

for any integer $a < b$ and $k$

---

I'm somewhat disturbed by what they expect us to do. I know what a distribution function and cumulative distributive function are, and I know what a piecewise function is. But I don't really see what they mean by: Express using $F$. Do I need to graph something ?

I asked the new version of ChatGPT that came out less than two weeks ago, and it says that I need to do for example for a):

$$P(X > 18) = 1 - P(X ≤ 18) = 1 - F(18)$$
$$P(X > k) = 1 - P(X ≤ k) = 1 - F(k)$$
$$P(X ≥ 5) = 1 - P(X ≤ 4) = 1 - F(4)$$
$$P(X ≥ k) = 1 - P(X ≤ (k-1)) = 1 - F(k-1)$$

And for b)

$$P(X = 5) = F(5) - F(4)$$
$$P(X = k) = F(k) - F(k-1)$$

Is this what they ask us to do ? This seems too simple, so I fear I missed something important

---

EDIT: c) would in this case be

$$P(4< X ≤11)=F(11)−F(4)$$
$$P(a<X≤b)=F(b)−F(a)$$
$$P(8≤X<25)=P(7<X≤24)=F(24)−F(7)$$
$$P(a≤X<b)=P((a−1)<X≤(b−1))=F(b−1)−F(a−1)$$

d) would in this case be

$$P(X≤2 \text{ or } X≥5)=P(X≤2)+P(X≥5) = F(2)+(1−F(4))$$
$$P(X≤6 \text{ and } X≥−3)=P(−3≤X≤6)=F(6)−F(−4)$$

Comment: @lonzaleggiera that's good to know, thank you ! Feel free to post an answer if you want, I will accept and upvote it so it doesn't appear in the unanswered questions. If I answer my own question, I can only accept it in two days

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I just added d), is this also correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all your answers are correct.  While these exercises are fairly simple, they're the sort of thing that will build your ability and confidence in manipulating them.  Just as practising musical scales and arpeggios will help you towards mastering virtuoso musical pieces, these exercises will help you master the more advanced uses of distribution functions.